# How to move the timestamp bounds for datetime in pandas (working with historical data)?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm working with historical data, and have some very old dates that are outside the timestamp bounds for pandas.  I've consulted the Pandas [Time series/date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) documentation, which has some information on [out of bounds spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans), but from this information, it still wasn't clear to me what, if anything I could do to convert my data into a `datetime` type.

I've also seen a few threads on Stack Overflow on this, but they either just point out the problem (i.e. nanoseconds, max range 570-something years), or suggest setting `errors = coerce` which turns 80% of my data into `NaT`s.

Is it possible to turn dates lower than the default Pandas lower bound into dates? Here's a sample of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['836', '655', '508', '793', '970', '1075', '1119', '969', '1166', '893'], 
                   'date': ['1671-11-25', '1669-11-22', '1666-05-15','1673-01-18','1675-05-07','1677-02-08','1678-02-08', '1675-02-15', '1678-11-28', '1673-12-23']})
```

Comment: Also, here's a good read in the [pandas docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans), funny enough they don't mention the concise method [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659928/9081267) is using

Comment: really curious as to what data you have going back to 1671?

Answer (score 3):

You can create [day periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) by lambda function:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))
```

Or like mentioned @Erfan in comment (thank you):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.Period)

print (df)
     id        date
0   836  1671-11-25
1   655  1669-11-22
2   508  1666-05-15
3   793  1673-01-18
4   970  1675-05-07
5  1075  1677-02-08
6  1119  1678-02-08
7   969  1675-02-15
8  1166  1678-11-28
9   893  1673-12-23
```

Comment: Simply `df['date'].apply(pd.Period)`, works as well